# How to have many langages or none in Andoid default Spell check and autocompletion?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, dictionary, spell-check

I type many languages. To have one language, is more problematic because of auto completion.

Comment: Do you mean many languages in one text or many languages in different texts (e.g. one text in English, the next in Italian, the other next in Catalan etc)?

Comment: Many languages in all. System should automatically detect all languages together. I may be typing many languages at the same time.

Comment: You can try SwiftKey, however it's restricted to 3 languages (and you can use all of them simultaneously only if they are based on the same alphabet, f.e. English and Russian will not work at the same time, but English and German will do).

Comment: @Alex.S sorry Swiftkey is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swiftkey is a good option again in Android 7.